# Arrow Character Code not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with the html entity Arrow Pointing Right Then Curving Down not displaying correctly in chrome (version 49.0.2623.110). It displays fine in FF and Safari but I get a box with a ? in chrome. Chrome is set to unicode(utf-8) and auto detect. Sorry if I formatted something incorrectly, this is my first question on here. Can someone help? Thanks.

my page is set to

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

It works here

```css
span {
 display: inline-block;
  content: "\2935";
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
   transform: rotate(180deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix( 
    M11=-1, M12=1.2246063538223773e-16, 
    M21=-1.2246063538223773e-16, 
    M22=-1, sizingMethod='auto expand');
   zoom: 1;
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

```html
<span>&#10549;</span>
```

But [this is what shows in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrxww.png)

I'm using a MacBook Pro early 2015 OS X El Capitan version 10.11.3

Comment: Do you want use the inline &#10549; or from the content \2935? If you use the pseudo element then you need to set it on :before or :after.

Comment: Sorry total newbie, I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I tried :before that didn't work. I got the code from this website http://htmlarrows.com/arrows/arrow-pointing-right-then-curving-down/ and copied the example. And like I said it works on FF and Safari but not chrome. Would it be a bug in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the font on the entity to Arial (I was using Raleway) and it works.